# Can not found module in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is my require module in app.js

```
 var Comment = require('/models/comments');
```

I created a folder called as modules and insert my schema into a file which is known as comments.js.

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');

 var CommentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  image: {
  type:String,
   unique : true
 },
 comment: {
   type: String,
 }



 });

  var Comment = module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment',CommentSchema);
   module.exports.createComment = function(newComment,callback){
        newComment.save(callback);
  }
```

I am getting this error

```
    Error: Cannot find module '/models/comments'
```

This is my file section

[image]

Comment: From which directory you are trying to access comment model ? if its from your app.js then change `require('/models/comments');` to `require('./models/comments');`

Comment: Yes ! thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require('/models/comments')` is pointing to the root of your filesystem.
To find it from `app.js` (based on your screenshot), change it to: `require('./models/comments')`